Почему каналы в Go более эффективны для параллельных вычислений, чем общая память?
Пример взят из книги "100 Ошибок Go"
Не могу понять почему использование каналов настолько выгоднее чем простое добавление массива? Они же должны нести расходы не только на создание, но и на операционную деятельность, т.к. за ними лежит структра.
Небольшие пояснения:
Count и Count3 работают со структурой типа Result
Count2 работает со структурой типа Result2

type Input struct {
    a int64
    b int64
}

type Result struct {
    sumA int64
    sumB int64
}

//[56]byte используется для расположение sumA и SumB в разных сегментах кеша
type Result2 struct {
    sumA int64
    _    [56]byte
    sumB int64
}

// 1048576 - 2^20 для наглядности
func CreateInput() []Input {
    input := make([]Input, 0, 1048576)

    for i := int64(0); i < 1048576; i++ {
        input = append(input, Input{
            a: i,
            b: i,
        })
    }

    return input
}

func Count(inputs []Input) Result {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)

    result := Result{}

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < len(inputs); i++ {
            result.sumA += inputs[i].a
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < len(inputs); i++ {
            result.sumB += inputs[i].b
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    return result
}

func Count2(inputs []Input) Result2 {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)

    result := Result2{}

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < len(inputs); i++ {
            result.sumA += inputs[i].a
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < len(inputs); i++ {
            result.sumB += inputs[i].b
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    return result
}

func Count3(inputs []Input) Result {
    var result Result
    sumAChan := make(chan int64)
    sumBChan := make(chan int64)

    go func() {
        var sumA int64
        for i := 0; i < len(inputs); i++ {
            sumA += inputs[i].a
        }
        sumAChan <- sumA
    }()

    go func() {
        var sumB int64
        for i := 0; i < len(inputs); i++ {
            sumB += inputs[i].b
        }
        sumBChan <- sumB
    }()

    result.sumA = <-sumAChan
    result.sumB = <-sumBChan

    return result
}

Update: результат сильно зависит от параметра -coverprofile
Count2 и Count3 очень близки, но почему -coverprofile оказывает такую сильную разницу, только на Count2?
без него средние результаты такие:
          │  stats.txt   │
          │    sec/op    │
Count-12    18.24m ±  2%
Count2-12   677.0µ ±  7%
Count3-12   689.8µ ± 12%
geomean     2.042m

          │  stats.txt  │
          │    B/op     │
Count-12    162.5 ± 19%
Count2-12   192.0 ±  6%
Count3-12   288.0 ±  0%
geomean     207.9

          │ stats.txt  │
          │ allocs/op  │
Count-12    4.000 ± 0%
Count2-12   4.000 ± 0%
Count3-12   4.000 ± 0%
geomean     4.000

Вот получившиеся результаты по бенчмаркам при 1048576 элементах c -coverprofile
cpu: AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics         
BenchmarkCount-12             49      25359128 ns/op         237 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCount2-12           295       3661261 ns/op         300 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCount3-12          1946        644967 ns/op         288 B/op          4 allocs/op

Вот получившиеся результаты по бенчмаркам без -coverprofile
BenchmarkCount-12             67          18467245 ns/op             209 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCount2-12          1833            597416 ns/op             211 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCount3-12          1938            734245 ns/op             288 B/op          4 allocs/op

код бенчмарка
var res test.Result
var res2 test.Result2
var res3 test.Result

// BenchmarkResult placeholder.
func BenchmarkCount(b *testing.B) {
    var sum test.Result
    b.StopTimer()

    input := test.CreateInput()

    b.StartTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        sum = test.Count(input)
    }

    res = sum
}

func BenchmarkCount2(b *testing.B) {
    var sum test.Result2
    b.StopTimer()

    input := test.CreateInput()

    b.StartTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        sum = test.Count2(input)
    }

    res2 = sum
}

func BenchmarkCount3(b *testing.B) {
    var sum test.Result
    b.StopTimer()

    input := test.CreateInput()

    b.StartTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        sum = test.Count3(input)
    }

    res3 = sum
}

команда для запуска бенчмарка, запускал через графический интерфейс в vscode
go test -benchmem -run=^$ -coverprofile=/tmp/vscode-govayH6A/go-code-cover -bench . alice/effective/internal/test


Вы точно ничего не напутали в тексте программы? Функции Count и Count2 у вас различаются лишь именем функции

функции отличаются типом структуры, с которым они работают. Первая функция работает со структурой "Result" и имеет два поля, а вторая со структурой "Result2" и имеет три поля

Ага, теперь понятно  (лучше подобную поясняющую информацию выносить в текст вопроса, а не заставлять выуживать ее из кода (да, я прочел комментарий про 2 cache lines)). Это какой процессор? Конечно, разница на порядок в ns/op, (наверное, как следствие реализации cache coherency) впечатляет. Ну, в 3-ей функции вы наверняка сами видите эффект от локальной переменой (которая скорее всего представлена машинным регистром) в качестве аккумулятора

Процессор amd x64 5600g. А локальная переменная присутствует в каждой функции, поэтому не понимаю как она может повлиять только в Count3.

Да, похоже на то. Только в Count и Count2 это поле в структуре. Странно все это (у вас в go). Хорошо бы дизассемблер посмотреть

Канал не был оптимизирован, в ассемблере имеется CALL runtime.chansend1(SB). Судя по всему sumA и sumB хранятся в регистрах AX и BX, а не кэше, как я изначально думал. Ассемблерный код горутин в Count2 и Count3 похож. Однако в Count2 вызов runtime.newobject(SB) в два раза чаще, количество NOP (5:4) и прочих мелких инструкций в Count3 меньше. Также в Count2 есть MOVUPS (перемещение данных из регистра в память). Думаю всё это, а также разница в размерах структуры Result и Result2, может объяснить подобный результат. Если напишете в ответе @avp, я помечу как решённое. Всем спасибо за помощь

Поделитесь пожалуйста командой, которой вы запускаете бенч. И самим кодом бенчмарка тоже. У меня немного совсем другие результаты получаются

@BeardedBeaver добавил в описание

@lol9kawaii, посмотрел на код внимательно и мне стало стыдно, что сразу не понял сути дела (хотя язык go мне неизвестен, но должен был догадаться...). / На самом деле существенная разница между Count, Count2 с одной стороны и Count3 в другой состоит в том, что в Count3 переменная, в которой в цикле накапливается сумма, локальна для каждого из потоков (она определена внутри go func() { ...), а в Count и Count2 аналогичная переменная (поле в структуре result) определена в общей для потоков памяти (вне go func() { ... в обеих процедурах). Отсюда и такая разница в результатах.


На изначальный вопрос, ответ я получил. В данном случае разница между каналами и расположением в разных сегментах кэша практически отсутствует. Влияние на результаты бенчмарков оказывает флаг -coverprofile
Вот получившиеся результаты по бенчмаркам при 1048576 элементах c -coverprofile
cpu: AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics         
BenchmarkCount-12             49      25359128 ns/op         237 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCount2-12           295       3661261 ns/op         300 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCount3-12          1946        644967 ns/op         288 B/op          4 allocs/op

Вот получившиеся результаты по бенчмаркам без -coverprofile
BenchmarkCount-12             67          18467245 ns/op             209 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCount2-12          1833            597416 ns/op             211 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCount3-12          1938            734245 ns/op             288 B/op          4 allocs/op


было бы неплохо приложить в ответ результаты бенчмарков без -coverprofile
